# Adding a zero to file names

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've recently discovered the power of sed; regular expressions seem like they'll take a lifetime to master. This tiny script uses both to add a zero before the single digit in file names.

Can this be done more easily without sed? Is the regex sound?

```
#!/bin/bash

# > addzero.sh <
# Adds a zero before the single digit in file names separated by an underscore.
# Designed to help keep files in sequence in directory listings. Otherwise, you get listings like
# "_0.txt, _1.txt, _10.txt, _11.txt, _12.txt, ..., _2.txt, _20.txt, _21.txt, _22.txt, ..."

for filename in $(ls -1 ./*); do
  if [[ $filename =~ _[0-9]\. ]]; then
    new_filename=$(echo $filename | sed -n 's/_\([0-9]\)\./_0\1\./p')
    mv $filename $new_filename
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What's wrong

```
for filename in $(ls -1 ./*); do
```

Ouch! As a general rule (with very few exceptions), [**do not use `ls` in scripts**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). What you wrote is almost equivalent to `for filename in ./*; do`, except that if there are any non-printable characters, whitespace characters, or `\[?*` in the file names, they will be mangled if you use `ls`. You don't need the `./` (except to ensure that the file name doesn't start with a `-`) but it doesn't hurt.

```
[[ $filename =~ _[0-9]\. ]]
```

could be written in a slightly simpler and more portable way: `[[ $filename = *_[0-9].* ]]`. And since you can use a simple glob pattern, you might as well not have iterated over all file names: `for filename in *_[0-9].*; do`. But there's a better way to express your script, to take advantage of `BASH_REMATCH`; see below.

```
echo $filename
```

**Always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions.** Exception: when you understand why you need to leave the double quotes off and why it's safe to do so. When the shell sees a variable substitution (`$foo` or `${foo}`) or a command substitution (`` `foo` `` or `$(foo)`) outside double quotes, the result of the substitution undergoes word splitting and globbing (filename generation). That was one of the problems with `$(ls -1 ./*)` earlier. This should be `echo "$filename"`.

In fact, it would be better `printf "%s" "$filename"`, because `echo` itself performs expansions. In bash, unless you've set non-default options to enable backslash expansion, the only problem is that a few arguments beginning with a `-` look like option, and in this specific case the filename will begin with `./`.

There is an edge case where your sed call won't work: if you have a file name that ends with a newline character. This doesn't happen in practice unless someone has made a mistake (like a rogue script or a bad copy-paste) or is deliberately trying to trick your script — so watch out in security contexts.

Incidentally, this is one of the few cases where it's safe to leave out the double quotes around a command substitution: in a variable assignment, there is an implicit pair of double quotes around the right-hand side, so `new_filename=$(…)` is equivalent to `new_filename="$(…)"`. Note that this does not extend to `export VARIABLE="$(value)"`, where the double quotes are necessary.

We now turn to your question about the use of `sed`. It is not necessary here; you can perform this substitution in bash. Bash has a pattern replacement [parameter substitution](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) feature, but it's limited to a constant replacement text. Bash also has a way to extract substrings from regexp matches with `=~`, through the `BASH_REMATCH` [variable](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables). After the match, `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` contains the portion of the string matched by the regexp, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contains the portion matched by the first parenthesized group and so on.

```
mv $filename $new_filename
```

Again, double quotes.

---

### A working script

One possibility is to extract the text to replace from the regexp match, then perform a string replacement on it. Since I'm not using `./*`, the file name may begin with a `-`, so I take care to use `--` on the call to `mv` to ensure that the file name isn't seen as an option.

```
for filename in *; do
  if [[ $filename =~ _[0-9]\. ]]; then
    from=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    mv -- "$filename" "${filename//$from/${from/_/_0}}"
  fi
done
```

Another possibility is to match the whole file name as a regexp and splice a `0` into the bits. Note that this will behave differently in a corner case: if there are several occurrences of `_[0-9]\.`, the code above replaces the first occurrence, while this replaces the last occurrence.

```
for filename in *; do
  if [[ $filename =~ ^(.*_)([0-9]\..*)$ ]]; then
    mv -- "$filename" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}0${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done
```

You can also use other constructs and avoid regexps altogether, but it's more complicated. An advantage is that the script then works in all shells, not just bash.

```
for filename in *_[0-9].*; do
  digit=${filename%.${filename##*_[0-9].}}; digit=${digit##*.}
  mv -- "$filename" "${filename%%_[0-9].*}_0${digit}.${filename#*_[0-9].*}"
done
```

There are other methods to perform this kind of file renaming. If you're on Debian or derivative (including Ubuntu) or have the `rename` Perl script that's floating around (note that this is not the standard Linux `rename` utility):

```
rename 's/_([0-9]\.)/_0$1/' *_[0-9].*
```

Or with mmv:

```
mmv -x '*_[0-9].*' '#1_0#2.#3'
```

Or in zsh, after `autoload zmv`:

```
zmv '(*_)([0-9].*)' '${1}0$2'
```

### Further reading

The [rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rename) and [quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rename) tags on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wow. Duly noted on excluding `ls`. It's given me headaches before, and my kludgy solution was to change the $IFS from a space to a line break, then restore it at the end of the script. This was just the kind of insight I was hoping for. Thanks.

Comment: Very thorough! Deserves more than one upvote, really :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regular expressions at all here. I'd use `printf` to pad the digits, and bash glob-patterns to extract the digits.

```
shopt -s extglob
for filename in *; do
  tmp=${filename%.txt}   # remove the ".txt" extension
  digits=${tmp##*_}      # remove everything up to the final underscore
  case $digits in
    +([0-9])) 
      # 'digits' contains only digits
      newname=${filename%_*}_$(printf "%02d" $digits).txt
      mv "$filename" "$newname"
      ;;
  esac
done
```